# Tapping on custom UIView fires wrong selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, xcode7.2

I have 2 custom-drawn subviews on a superview and 2 gesture recognisers to call 2 different methods. Problem is, when I tap on any of the views, tap on the second subview still fires the first method! Here's my code:

```
- (void) addTapGestures{
self.firstTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(firstSelector)];
self.firstTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.firstSubview addGestureRecognizer:self.firstTap];

self.secondTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(secondSelector)];
self.secondTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.secondSubview addGestureRecognizer:self.secondTap];
```

Will appreciate any hints!

Comment: I just don't get this line self.firstSubview = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] , should it be self.firstTap = [UITapGesture]

Comment: @NickCatib Yep, thanks for pointing out the typo, edited.

Comment: you have a typo in your code. self.firstSubview = should be self.firstTap =

Comment: @Tuslareb, yes, I was changing names and made this typo. Edited now.

Comment: Isn't your second subview a subview of the first subview?

Comment: @Tuslareb no, they are two different subviews added to the main view.

Comment: Code looks correct. Maybe you should check whether self.firstSubview is equal to self.secondSubview?

Comment: @MaciejKozieł good point, but debug shows they have different memory addresses. So in general - everything looks correct, but somehow does not work as expected.

Comment: @Kmkrn Ok, last guess. Does these subviews overlaps, and one of them has disabled user interaction? If not, I think you should provide more details.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł looks like you were right, the first view had the wrong frame (which was impossible to detect visually) and this resulted to views overlapping. Please write your comment as an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from my comments. Common problems I can think of: 
1) `self.firstSubview` is equal to `self.secondSubview` 
2) Views are overlapping and/or user interaction is disabled on one of them. 
Second one turned out to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the tapped view by using hitTest method of UIView. Based on that you can decide which method should be called. Put this method in your superview containing both of your subviews.
Here is an example.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

   if ([self.firstSubView isEqual:hitView])
   {
       // You clicked on firstSubView, by returning firstSubView it will call its respective selector method
       return self.firstSubView;
   }
   else if ([self.secondSubView isEqual:hitView])
   {
      return self.secondSubView;
   }

   return hitView;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this method called automatically?

Comment: @Kmkrn yes. Its a method of UIView

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0:**

Try: -

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

//make condition here
}
```

OR

Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer. In the ViewController, install the recognizer on the “parent” view.

```
var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"pan:")
pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

In the recognizer action, first grab the location of the event. Then, depending on the state of the recogniser, implement the different parts of the drag functionality.

```
func pan(rec:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {            
        var p:CGPoint = rec.locationInView(self.view)
        var center:CGPoint = CGPointZero

        switch rec.state {
        case .Began:
            println("began")
            self.selectedView = view.hitTest(p, withEvent: nil)
            if self.selectedView != nil {
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.selectedView!)
            }
case .Changed:
            if let subview = selectedView {
                center = subview.center
                var distance = sqrt(pow((center.x - p.x), 2.0) + pow((center.y - p.y), 2.0))
                println("distance \(distance)")

            if subview is MyView {
                if distance > threshold {
                    if shouldDragX {
                        subview.center.x = p.x - (p.x % snapX)
                    }
                    if shouldDragY {
                        subview.center.y = p.y - (p.y % snapY)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
case .Ended:
   if let subview = selectedView {
      if subview is MyView {
          // do whatever
      }
   }
   // must do this of course
   selectedView = nil
}
```